# why does my !=0 not work in my while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

Write a program that simulates a cashier terminal. Assume that a customer is purchasing an unknown number of different merchandise items, possibly with multiple quantities of each item. Use a while loop to prompt for the unit price and quantity. The loop should continue until the unit price is zero. Display a subtotal for each item. After the loop display the total amount due. Use currency format where appropriate.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter item price or zero to quit: ");
        double price = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the quantity for this item: ");
        int qty = input.nextInt();

        double Sub_Total = price * qty;

        System.out.printf("Total of this item is $%4.2f", Sub_Total);
        System.out.println();


        double Total = 0;

        while(price != 0) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter item price or zero to quit: ");
            price = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Enter the quantity for this item");
            qty = input.nextInt();

            Sub_Total = price * qty;

            System.out.printf("Total of this item is $%4.2f", Sub_Total);
            System.out.println();


            Total += Sub_Total; 
        }
        System.out.printf("Total is $%5.2f" + Total);

    }

}
```

I'm doing a program for school, and I can't figure out why my while loop doesn't end when i type in 0.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `System.out.prinln` to dump the value of `price`?

Comment: you declared price as double and comparing with `0` try changing `0` to `0.0`

Comment: By the way, by convention, java variable names should be start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @RajuKomati - That won't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

The loop does end when you enter `0`; the problem is your `println` statement is outside of the loop. Your code should look like this:

```
      ...
      Total += Sub_Total;
      System.out.printf("Total is $%5.2f", Total);
      }
   }
}
```

If you want your program to end right after entering `0` then you could add an `if` statement:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter item price or zero to quit: ");
double price = input.nextDouble();

if (price <= 0) {
    System.out.println("input: zero - program terminated.");
    return; 
}
...
```

In order for this to work effectively the code needs to be restructured. It could also be optimized to remove redundancy; the following should handle the conditions and exit properly:

```
import java.util.*;

class Untitled {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double total = 0;
    double subtotal = 0;
    double qty = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter item price or zero to quit: ");
    double price = input.nextDouble();

    while (price > 0) {

        System.out.println("Enter the quantity for this item: ");
        qty = input.nextDouble();

        subtotal = price * qty;
        total += subtotal;

        System.out.printf("Total of this item is $%4.2f", subtotal);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("\nEnter item price or zero to quit: ");
        price = input.nextDouble();

        if (price <= 0)
            break; 
        }
        System.out.printf("Total is $%5.2f", total);
    }
}
```

[As mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60426872/why-does-my-0-not-work-in-my-while-loop/60427032#comment106897574_60426872) follow conventions by using lowercase letters for variable names.

Answer (score 0):

After taking the price input you can check it using if condition if price is `0` you can use `break` to stop the loop

```
public class Program4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter item price or zero to quit: ");
        double price = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the quantity for this item: ");
        int qty = input.nextInt();

        double Sub_Total = price * qty;

        System.out.printf("Total of this item is $%4.2f", Sub_Total);
        System.out.println();


        double Total = 0;

        while(price != 0) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter item price or zero to quit: ");
            price = input.nextDouble();

            if(price == 0)
            break;

            System.out.println("Enter the quantity for this item");
            qty = input.nextInt();

            Sub_Total = price * qty;

            System.out.printf("Total of this item is $%4.2f", Sub_Total);
            System.out.println();


            Total += Sub_Total; 
        }
        System.out.printf("Total is $%5.2f",Total);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the solution for you, here I have given comment where your code has problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter item price or zero to quit: ");
        double price = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the quantity for this item: ");
        int qty = input.nextInt();

        double Sub_Total = price * qty;

        System.out.printf("Total of this item is $%4.2f", Sub_Total);
        System.out.println();


        double Total = Sub_Total;  //changed this line to get correct total

        while(price != 0) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter item price or zero to quit: ");
            price = input.nextDouble();

            if(price == 0.0) 
                break;

            System.out.println("Enter the quantity for this item");
            qty = input.nextInt();

            Sub_Total = price * qty;

            System.out.printf("Total of this item is $%4.2f", Sub_Total);
            System.out.println();


            Total += Sub_Total; 

        }
        System.out.printf("Total is $%5.2f", Total); //this also needs to be changed to print output in correct format, 
                                                     //otherwise you will get missing element exception

    }
```